# Design PC mainboard from scratch

Tags: pcb, intel, pc

As a hobbist I always wish to design    own PC mainboard. I want to try build such PC based on I3-390m CPU (pga988) and bd82hm55 chipset. Any clue where I can find some datasheet or circuits that can help me to wire up everything? I also wonder if such mainboard can exists without chipset. I know such task is not easy but I like to try for fun.

Comment: You should start small

Comment: This is beyond what hobbyists can do because of the 16-layer board required. There are factories which can do such a thing for you, but it would be ridiculously expensive for small batches.

Comment: If you wanted to develop your own small computer, try with a PIC or AVR µC. Or a Z80 or 6502 if you want to go fully retro. It's certainly possible to build decent machines (in their class) with these with hobbyist resources.

Comment: Sorry, but this is very bad idea. A pga988 is based on a 36 x 36 ball array, with the inner balls typically about 10 rows or columns in from the outer balls. Getting these inner signals "out from under" the chip will take a LOT of layers. Particularly since you are not experienced in layout, figure more rather than fewer layers - I'd estimate 10 layers minimum. Although you don't realize it, you'll need to reserve several (like 4) layers just for ground and power. And trust me, a 10-layer pcb of the size you want will be horrendously expensive in small quantities.

Comment: People are telling you that this is a bad idea, but I'm going to say that it's your money and if you want to spend it on this go right ahead--but this question is not a good fit for the site as it's too broad.

Comment: *not easy but I like to try for fun.* Trust us, you will not think this is "fun" anymore after going through all datasheets and try to make sense of them, learning about matched length lines (which you'll need to make the memory work), writing your own firmware (BIOS / UEFI) and knowing what it will cost to manufacture that PCB. Then your first design will have issues, or better: it will simply refuse to work. Go design a board for a PIC or ATMega uC and work your way up if you want to keep the "fun" and not cry in frustration.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I must point out that designing a motherboard is a considerable effort for a team of designers, let alone for a single hobby designer.

Where should you start? 
Go to the Intel website, and download the datasheet for the specific processor you want to use. There you will find all the information you need that will allow you to find further information for the circuit you want to design. Intel like any other IC manufacturer also provide reference designs for you, however, these are very generic designs, that you have to tailor to your requirements.

Possible pitfalls.

- What experience do you have in circuit design? You need to know what you are doing otherwise you are just wasting your money.
- How much experience you have in PCB design? You are looking at a number of Hi-speed circuits, that require impedance control and length matching of traces, such as DDR3, and PCIe busses.
- What assembly equipment do you have? a simple soldering iron, and a hot gun won't cut it. You need a reflow over, with good temperature control, and a proper process. The most likely outcome is that you will have to have it assembled by some professional. This will be expensive.
- The PCB will be very expensive, you will look at a minimum of 8/10 layers, which alone will cost more than a fully functional assembled motherboard in a shop.
- BIOS, you will need to make that one as well, as it is likely that you will want to personalise the board design to include some features that are not available on the market.
- How much time do you have? The layout alone will take in excess of one month working eight hours a day, and that is if you are experienced.
- Mistakes. Even the best designers do mistakes, and in such a large design, mistakes are unavoidable. Consider at least a couple of manufacturing iterations.

I can estimate that this project is going to cost well over $2.5k, and that is giving your time a value of $0. 
I wish you the best of luck, however, you will find that after working on it for over a year, the parts that you want to put into the design will be out of production and unavailable to buy. (The I3-390m is already out of production).

If you really want to design a process board, I would rather look into a RaspberryPi type of board; these designs have sufficient challenges, without being impossible to tackle by a single designer. Look at some clones such as OrangePi or similar, where you can find the schematics already online.
Another approach can be to look at using a SoM, such as the RaspberryPi CM3, which allows you to define the peripherals, and mechanical layout, without having to go into the complex design of a processor board.

Good luck!

Comment: look into a RaspberryPi type of board -- good suggestion.

Comment: If full PC compatibility is not needed, one may run U-Boot in a bare metal mode. Nevertheless it will require FSP blob to be provided by Intel.